# How Cordova support Network Security Config introduced by Android 7.0?

Tags: android, cordova

Android 7.0 intorduced Network Security Config to support use custom CAs, but how Cordova support that? I can not find any hint from docs of Cordova.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can achieve this by adding the `edit-config` tag to the Android platform in your `config.xml`, this is supported by Cordova Android Plugin v7.0.

You will need to create the Network Security Config file that you would create for a native Android application using the examples from [Google](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config).

Next in the Cordova `config.xml` you can use the `edit-config` tag to add the `networkSecurityConfig` attribute to the Application tag.  Then you just need to copy the Network Security Config file as a resource for your application to the `res/xml` directory.

Here is an example of how this might look in your applications config.xml

```
...
<platform name="android">
    <edit-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
    </edit-config>
    <resource-file src="network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
</platform>
...
```

Comment: create the network_security_config.xml file at the root (same with config.xml path),
and fill with this:

`
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <base-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <trust-anchors>
            <certificates src="system" />
        </trust-anchors>
    </base-config>
</network-security-config>
`

Comment: or fix the src: <resource-file src="res/xml/network_security_config.xml"...

Answer (score 5):

What James [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166025/how-cordova-support-network-security-config-introduced-by-android-7-0/51991830#51991830) works but if you have an application where you can't specify a domain or wants to allow clear text traffic for all domains, we need to set `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` in `platforms/android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` in `<application>` tag.

Because, in Android P (version 9, API level 28), cleartext support is by default disabled. To achieve this, just add the following in your `config.xml` inside `<platform name="android">`:

```
<edit-config file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
</edit-config>
```

Comment: this is not work to me then i change to `android:cleartextTrafficPermitted="true"` still does not work, any one can help ?

Comment: @ana You can add this to your security config xml file for Android.  ex.  ```<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">akamaihd.net</domain>```

Comment: I had to add the android namespace definition for this to work: ```<edit-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
    <application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />
</edit-config>```

Comment: This should work, but it's not. The easiest possible fix is to lower the sdk version to something <= 27. Example:  `<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="27" />`, then run `cordova prepare android`. (Forgot to mention, I'm using cordova-android version 8.0.0)

Comment: This is working fine for me in `cordova-android >= 8.0.0`

Comment: My security config file is always overwritten after running the command 'ionic cordova run android' when i try to add something.

Comment: How do you know that it's being overwritten? @Tijl.Reynhout

Comment: I already fixed it. In ionic 5 adding cleartext permitted and not using the network config file does the trick

Answer (score 0):

I am using Cordova 11 with android sdk 30. Just using the
`<application android:usesCleartextTraffic="true" />` didn't
work for me. XHR Requests to non https urls just reported 'Error'.
I got it working with the following:

In config.xml I added:

```
<platform name="android">
        <edit-config xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" file="app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        </edit-config>
        <resource-file src="res/xml/network_security_config.xml" target="app/src/main/res/xml/network_security_config.xml" />
 </platform>
```

Contents of res/xml/network_security_config.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>10.1.36.67</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Note the use of the local res/xml folder for the network_security_config.xml file. Placing it in the main platform/app directory won't work and will result in the file being overwritten anyway.