# Ionic network security config

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3, ionic4

Hello i am working on ionic application. with executing this command `ionic cordova build android  --prod --release`. it does generate the unasigned apk file,but it also show error in network_security_config file.

**Error**

`app\src\main\res\xml\network_security_config.xml:4: Error: Missing includeSubdomains attribute [NetworkSecurityConfig]
    <domain>localhost</domain>`

i tried multiple solutions, but doesn't work for me.

**Reference**

[How to allow all Network connection types HTTP and HTTPS in Android (9) Pie?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51902629/how-to-allow-all-network-connection-types-http-and-https-in-android-9-pie)

[How Cordova support Network Security Config introduced by Android 7.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51166025/how-cordova-support-network-security-config-introduced-by-android-7-0)

Could someone help me with this?

Comment: Can  you add what is the content of the network_security_config.xml? Do you have any custom rules?

Comment: @yazantahhan   `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain>localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
` there is no custom rules

Answer (score 6):

Go to the `resources/android/xml/network_security_config.xml` and add `includeSubdomains="true"` to the domain property. It should be like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
        <domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: yazantahhan thank you for your answer it fix the issue of includeSubdomains attribute, but on build it does show some other errors. before this error was not there **Error** `Explanation for issues of type "MissingDefaultResource":
   If a resource is only defined in folders with qualifiers like -land or -en,
   and there is no default declaration in the base folder (layout or values
   etc), then the app will crash if that resource is accessed on a device
   where the device is in a configuration missing the given qualifier.` looking forward to hear from you.

Comment: Can you try to enter `ionic cordova resources` then try to build

Comment: If this didnt work, try to remove the platform and add it again

Comment: firstly i do remove the platform, then build cordova resources, then add platform when i run this command `ionic cordova build android --prod --release` it does generate the config.xml file in android platform also right?, there the link of resources is getting wrong in that config file.

Comment: I didn't get this error before actually. Which file is he complaining about? Is it some of the splash screen images? Maybe this thread is related https://github.com/apache/cordova-android/issues/689

Comment: Reference folder `platforms\android\app\src\main\res\drawable-port` it is about splash screen images, and this thread is related https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-splashscreen/issues/214. its happen in cordova 9.0 build. too resolve this issue do i need to downgrade the cordova version.

Comment: **Error Screen** https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Rte3.png have a look in this error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/201579/discussion-between-yazantahhan-and-ahsan-mustafa).